How to list nearby English words in Wiktionary?
I like using Wiktionary generally, but it seems to lack a way to see other words that would be nearby in a printed dictionary.  This can be useful to find a word that you don't quite remember, but can make a fair guess as to how the spelling starts out.  This is also handy if you are interested in related words that would have similar spellings, such as a compound word where you know the first component word.
I'm familiar with Wikipedia, and like that Wiktionary has ways to list (word) pages under the "Special pages" tool.  There is one tool listed there that gets a good ways towards yielding such a list of words, which is "All pages with prefix" under "Lists of pages".  The problem with that is that Wiktionary includes words from many languages, so the list you get has many irrelevant words if you're looking for English words only (or for some other language).
There should be something better for this, but if there is it's not very obvious.

The only way to do this that I've found is to use the category "English lemmas", which apparently lists all pages having English words.
Using this directly will work, but navigation is annoyingly clumsy. First you scroll down to a table of single letters and of two-letter combinations, and click on one of them.  That takes you to a page of the category which includes 200 English words, beginning with words starting with that letter or those letters.  Then you can scroll down past the navigation table to a section listing the words.  Often that doesn't get you close enough to your target word, so you have to use a "next page" link at the bottom, or modify the URL in your browser interface.  To do the latter you change the part of URL that says something like &from=FO to have your target word follow the equals sign (like &from=foot if your word is "foot").
Fortunately, many web browsers allow you to add a search shortcut to get a word list.  In Chrome this is called a "site search"; in Firefox it is called a "keyword search". To create this, you would give a parameterized URL like this:
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_lemmas&pagefrom=%s#mw-pages

(The %s is where your target word will be substituted, and the #mw-pages causes automatic scroll to the right part of the page.)  If you name the shortcut, say, "wordlist", then typing wordlist foot would bring up a list starting at "foot".
A useful aspect of the category list is that if you hover over a word in the word list, a popup will appear giving a short form of the word's definition.
